# Customize default options when creating a new Site

Tags: sharepoint-site

Is there a way to customize options in **Create a New Site** -page of SharePoint? We want to default Permissions to "Use unique Permissions", and Navigation Inheritance as "Use toplink bar from parent".

Comment: You talk about Site Pages, but I think you mean Sites. Sites are sublevels on your SharePoint (e.g. `/Projects/`), whereas Site Pages are .aspx pages (e.g. `Home.aspx`). The default behavior when creating a _Site_ is that you are defining the user permissions and the navigation inheritance, so I'm assuming you want to define new default options in here?

Comment: I meant page for "creating new site".